# Restkit MultiForm Post with an Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, restkit

## Problem

I've been trying to post to the server with a multiform request that includes an image attachment.  I haven't had trouble getting the image to the server, it is the other information that is not sending correctly.

## Details

I'm using object mapping to configure several different attributes when receiving objects from the server:

```
//Using a custom class to map object I receive to
RKObjectMapping * memoryMapper = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MemoContent class]];
[memoryMapper mapAttributes:@"created", @"user", @"participants", @"tags", @"text", @"kind", @"video", @"location", nil];
[memoryMapper mapKeyPath:@"_id" toAttribute:@"memoryID"];

//MediaMapper handles the data needed for the Image attachments
RKObjectMapping * mediaMapper = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MemoMedia class]];
[mediaMapper mapKeyPath:@"processed" toAttribute:@"processed"];
[mediaMapper mapKeyPath:@"original" toAttribute:@"original"];
[mediaMapper mapKeyPath:@"mime" toAttribute:@"mimeType"];
[memoryMapper mapKeyPath:@"media" toRelationship:@"rawMedia" withMapping:mediaMapper];

//
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:memoryMapper forKeyPath:@"memories"];
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded;
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].acceptMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

Then, when it comes time to post a photo I update configurations as follows:

```
 RKObjectMapping * memoryMapper = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MemoContent class]];
[memoryMapper mapAttributes:@"created", @"participants",  nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:memoryMapper forClass:[MemoContent class]];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:memoryMapper forKeyPath:@"memory"];
```

Participants are people tagged with the photo.  Here is how I'm posting it, similar to this https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Attach-a-File-to-an-RKObjectLoader

```
   [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:theMemory usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader * loader){

    RKObjectMapping* serializationMapping = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] serializationMappingForClass:[MemoContent class]];
    NSLog(@"serializationMapping: %@", serializationMapping);
    loader.delegate = APP; //main app delegate posting, updating
    NSError* error = nil;
    RKObjectSerializer * serializer = [[RKObjectSerializer alloc] initWithObject:theMemory mapping:serializationMapping];
    NSDictionary * dictionary = [serializer serializedObject:&error];  
    RKParams * params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:dictionary];
    NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theMemory.photo); //image data
    [params setData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/png" forParam:@"attachment"];
    loader.params = params;
    loader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded;
    }];
```

The server is receiving the image as planned, and actually does receive the 'created' and 'participants' unfortunately it's in a strange format that the server doesn't understand.  It includes line breaks and such `participants (\n   19843589323 \n created: \n 3-31-2012 00:00`  (something like that, I will update when I have access to the logs.

I will give you any extra info you need. Would offer reputation for it if I had enough to do so ;)

Comment: Do you mean a POST with Content-type `multipart/form-data`? Do you insist on using RestKit for this?

Comment: I would prefer to stick with Restkit, and I do believe a multipart/form-data is right.. but could you elaborate?

Comment: Can't help you with RestKit, but if it's not a requirement, many other solutions are available. This morning I put a gist online for playing with multipart/form-data, have a look [https://gist.github.com/3786554](https://gist.github.com/3786554)

Comment: I know its been awhile but I decided to give yours a shot because I just can't get what I need out of Restkit.  You have a method called NSData randomWithLength... where is that coming from?

Comment: Also you have a escapeforURL method that isn't there either

Comment: Good to hear. I updated the gist ([https://gist.github.com/3786554](https://gist.github.com/3786554)) to be more self-contained. The example at the top should demonstrate how you can upload an image as `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In [RestKit 0.20.0-pre3](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0-pre3/Classes/RKObjectManager.html), `RKObjectManager` does have method `multipartFormRequestWithObject:method:path:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:`

Comment: I actually did end up using this technique, silly me for not adding it to accepted answers.  Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

An example of this task can be found at the [RestKit Github page](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#post-an-object-with-a-file-attachment):

```objective-c
Article *article = [Article new];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image.png"];

// Serialize the Article attributes then attach a file
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] multipartFormRequestWithObject:article method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:nil parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                                name:@"article[image]"
                            fileName:@"photo.png"
                            mimeType:@"image/png"];
}];

RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation]; // NOTE: Must be enqueued rather than started
```

Comment: Why enqueued rather than started?